# What is the Alphabetical Inequality Test?

Tags: sorting

Mathematica can sort `{"b","d","a","c"}` into `{"a","b","c","d"}` with a simple application of `Sort`. What ordering function/command is being used?

It isn't `<`: `"a" < "b"` doesn't return `True` or `False`, just `a < b`.

I'm trying to sort a large data set that contains both strings and numeric values. An example:

`data = {{9, 8, "b"}, {4, 2, "d"}, {0, 3, "a"}, {4, 9, "c"}}`.

I can sort by the second element of each set:

`Sort[data, #2[[2]] > #1[[2]] &]` returns

`{{4, 2, "d"}, {0, 3, "a"}, {9, 8, "b"}, {4, 9, "c"}}`.

But `Sort`ing by the third element doesn't work:

`Sort[data, #2[[3]] > #1[[3]] &]` returns `data` unchanged:

`{{9, 8, "b"}, {4, 2, "d"}, {0, 3, "a"}, {4, 9, "c"}}`.

It feels like a hack, but I can sort using `Ordering` and `OrderedQ`:

`data[[Ordering[data[[All, 3]]]]]` returns

`{{0, 3, "a"}, {9, 8, "b"}, {4, 9, "c"}, {4, 2, "d"}}`, as does

`Sort[data, OrderedQ[{#1[[3]], #2[[3]]}] &]`.

Neither feels natural. Is there a lexicographical/alphabetical "inequality" command, or is it just `OrderedQ`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`AlphabeticOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AlphabeticOrder.html):

```
data = {{9, 8, "b"}, {4, 2, "d"}, {0, 3, "a"}, {4, 9, "c"}};

Sort[
    data, 
    AlphabeticOrder[ #1[[3]], #2[[3]] ]&
]
```

> {{0, 3, "a"}, {9, 8, "b"}, {4, 9, "c"}, {4, 2, "d"}}

Comment: That's it. I didn't seem to be using the right search terms online to find that command.

Answer (score 5):

`AlphabeticOrder` does not exist in version 10.1 which I use, but I don't believe it is necessary here.  I argue that [`Order`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Order.html) and [`OrderedQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderedQ.html) are the more canonical (and certainly general) functions.

Additionally, where possible you should make use of [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) (e.g. `SortBy[data, #[[3]] &]`) or [`Ordering`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) (as you already did) rather than `Sort`, as these are [more efficient](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78183/121) methods.

An alternative to `OrderedQ` if you have need of `Sort` itself:

```
Sort[data, 0 < Order[#[[3]], #2[[3]]] &]
Sort[data, 0 > Order[#[[3]], #2[[3]]] &]
```

> ```
> {{0, 3, "a"}, {9, 8, "b"}, {4, 9, "c"}, {4, 2, "d"}}
> {{4, 2, "d"}, {4, 9, "c"}, {9, 8, "b"}, {0, 3, "a"}}
> ```

This is actually more concise than `AlphabeticOrder`.

Comment: In law they say *"lex specialis derogat legi generali"*: Sometimes the more special function has its merits and is maybe is less abstract? `AlphabeticOrder` on the other hand is more general than `Order` because English is not the only language out there... ;-)

Comment: @gwr I didn't notice that AlphabeticOrder handled different languages; that's nice!  I have already voted for your answer.  And thanks for the Latin lesson.